# Asymptotic complexity between n! and n^n

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

What would be the example of a function f(n) that is asymptotically slower than O(n^n) and faster than O(n!), i.e.

O(n!) < O(f(n))< O(n^n)

?

Answer (score 0):

f: n ↦ (n+1)! is one such function.

Comment: where does it go up to-- until which value of k in (n+k)! ?

Comment: Actually, I am not sure anymore. Obviously, O(n!) < O((n+1)!), but I do not know how to prove O((n+1)!) < O(nⁿ).